# Is there a Jupyter theme that colors variables based on data type?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter

I'm working in JupyterLab and would love to be able to see the datatype of the contents of every variable I'm working with based on color, where dictionaries would be, say, yellow; strings, green; dataframes, red; etc. Does this exist? If not, is the a reasonable way of setting it up manually?

Example:

```
dictionary_var = dict()

dataframe_var = pd.DataFrame()

string_var = 'string'

set_var = set()

list_var = list()
```

In the above cell, each variable would be a different color based on the datatype of its contents. It could also be potentially nice if those colors mapped onto the syntax, so that the brackets of a list were the same color as a variable containing a list, and the apostrophes/characters of a string the same color as a variable containing a string, etc.

Comment: Show a sample of the code or output (or notebook cell) and identify the objects you want colored.  In an `ipython` session which I use, code gets highlights like strings and Python keywords.  But if I assign say `x='astring', the quoted characters are colored, but `x` is not.  Python variables don't have an inherent type.  The type depends on what's currently assigned to it.  Type is a runtime property, not something that can be determined by code syntax.

Comment: So what I'm wondering is if there's a theme that will color `x` according to its contents, e.g., the same color as `'asstring'`. Even though type is a runtime property, in some cases at least type can be inferred through syntax.